# Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause'

Tags: database, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have reviewed every post and tried a few recommendations but nothing is working. My code has been fine -- but Gravity Forms did an update and messed up the database tables the data was pulling from so I edited that but the data is still not pulling properly and I am getting the error: Unknown column 'value' in 'where clause' when I turn on debug.

Can anyone see why I am getting this error? The page should be retrieving a list of team members based on the value they have entered in a graavity form field.....all was fine until the update.

Here is the code that is causing the issues - specifically the $get_team_ids and $user_email lines seem to be the offenders.

```
function showstep1(){
$concate='';
$postid = get_the_ID();
$post_7 = get_post($postid); 

if( is_mr() ) {
//print_r($post_7->post_title);
 }
//echo $postid;

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "walking_steps";
$table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix . "users";
$table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "gf_entry_meta";
$get_team_ids = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name2 where value = '" .$post_7->post_title. "'");

 if( is_mr() ) {
     //print_r($get_team_ids);
     //print_r( $getuserids );
 }

 $users = array();
 if(!empty($get_team_ids)){
 foreach ($get_team_ids as $idlead) {
        $user_email = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT value FROM wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE form_id=4 AND lead_id=$idlead->lead_id AND field_number=3");
        if( empty( $user_email ) ) {
        $user_email = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT value FROM wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE form_id=1 AND lead_id=$idlead->lead_id AND field_number=2");
        }
        if( $user_email ) $users[] = $user_email;

      //$concate .= $idlead->lead_id.',';
 }
 $concate = substr($concate, 0,-1);
 //echo $concate;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unknown column 'value' in 'WHERE clause' would usually indicate that the column does not exist in the table.

You say that this is also happening for the other line 'user_email' which also is trying to SELECT the column 'value' again, if this causing you a problem, the column name is not correct it would seem.

Is it the correct header for the column? Seems like an ambiguous name. Try renaming the column 'value' to something less generic or change the where clause to

"WHERE table_name2.value = "

If this is not the column header, please replace 'value' with the correct column header

EDIT: Correct Code below as per comments

Replace all instances of 'value' with 'meta_value'

Comment: I did not originally write this code so I am a little baffled by it myself - and that was my thought. But the code always worked like this - I have a development website that works fine with it written this way so I am even more confused. Let me see if I can make sense of what you wrote...

Comment: Hi Jill,

Sorry if it wasn't clear enough, I can't really get much more info from your question without seeing the database structure and values. However the term 'value' as a column header seems a little wrong. 

Do you have access to the database?

Comment: I am in it now....it is the gf_entry_meta db, only columns are id, form_id, entry_id, meta_ky and meta_value - the data I need it stored in the meta_value

Comment: OK, change the SQL to say 'meta_value' wherever it currently says 'value'

Comment: I had tried that it just gives me a whole new array of errors.

Comment: It is related to the $user_email queries that are used to pull in the team member names ---

Comment: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$lead_id in 
    /homepages/42/d616961616/htdocs/vwrr/wp- 
    content/themes/steps/give/single-give-form/featured-image.php on 
    line 44

    WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
    the right syntax to use near 'AND field_number=3' at line 1]
    SELECT meta_value FROM wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE form_id=4 
    AND lead_id= AND field_number=3`

Comment: There is no value being sent in for lead_id 

Make sure this is set first

Comment: Just went back to the original database and there WAS a value field....that is why that was there....

Comment: So meta_value should work, but it is now causing an issue with the lead_id. That get_team_ids is what passes the value to idlead, so not sure now why that is not working properly if the meta value is correct.

Comment: Still seems like  and error with lead_id being blank